# Implementing RLE algorithm in C++ meta programming style

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, template-meta-programming

I have implemented a simple recursive algorithm for RLE (Run Length Encoding).

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
struct RLE {
    static size_t cnt;

    static void Compress(char const p[]) {                
        // Check current char with next char. If they are not same then print the current character and its count. Then reset the counter to 0 for next itetation.
        if (!(*p == *(p + 1))) {
            cout << cnt << *p;
            cnt = 0;
        }
        // Call the function again with new character
        RLE<N - 1>::Compress(p + 1);
    }
};

template <size_t N>
size_t RLE<N>::cnt = 1 + RLE<N - 1>::cnt;

template <>
struct RLE<0> {
    static size_t cnt;
    static void Compress(char const[]) {
    }
};;

//template<>  // On uncomenting this like why do I get a error "extraneous template<>, in declaration of variable cnt."
size_t RLE<0>::cnt = 0;

int main(void) {
    char const str[]{"mmatsss"};

    // -1 since sizeof includes terminating null char.
    RLE<sizeof(str) - 1>::Compress(str);
}
```

For an input like "mmatsss", the expected output is "2m1a1t3s", but what I am getting is "1m1a1t1s", i.e the code prints only the first char of the group. I am unable to figure out the bug in the code. Can someone please take a look at it, and help me to understand what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: That code produces 6m5a4t1s using gcc.  Please ensure you have the exact code, exact output, and tell us your compiler.  [Mcve] is required.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevrsumont

I have compiled the code on Cxxdroid mobile compiler and getting the result i have mentioned in the post, but when i tried with online compilers i am getting the result you have mentioned, probablly i need to change my compiler.
side question, is the downvote due to incomplete, not verifyable and/or the question is not up to the standards of StackOverflow

Comment: I used c4droid.  And read code and it should do what c4dtoid says.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont 
I do not have C4Droid app on my phone. Cxxdroid was free so i was using it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to figure out the bug in the code, can someone please take a look at it, and help me to understand what am i doing wrong here.

The problem is that you initialize the static member `cnt` as follows

```
template <size_t N>
size_t RLE<N>::cnt = 1 + RLE<N - 1>::cnt;

size_t RLE<0>::cnt = 0;
```

so you get `cnt == N`, when the compiler use the `RLE<N - 1>::cnt` value initialized (g++ case), `cnt == 1` when `N > 0`, when the compiler use zero for `RLE<N - 1>::cnt` (clang++ case).

I don't know who's right but the point is that when you write

```
        cout << cnt << *p;
        cnt = 0;
```

you print `cnt` in `RLE<N>` -- so `N` or `1`, according the case -- and you set to zero the `cnt` in `RLE<N>`.

But when you set to zero the `cnt` in `RLE<N>`, the `cnt` in `RLE<N-1>` remain unchanged (so `N-1` or `1`, according the case).

I don't see much metaprogramming in your code but seems to me that a possible correction is set all `cnt` to 1

```
template <size_t N>
size_t RLE<N>::cnt = 1;

size_t RLE<0>::cnt = 1;
```

and set `RNE<N-1>::cnt` as `cnt + 1` in `Compress()`

```
static void Compress(char const p[])
{                
    if (!(*p == *(p + 1)))
    {
        cout << cnt << *p;
        cnt = 0u;
    }

    RLE<N - 1>::cnt = cnt+1u;  <---  add this line

    RLE<N - 1>::Compress(p + 1);
}
```

But, frankly, I prefer your original (not metaprogramming) code.

Comment: @ma66,
Thank you for going through the code. I wanted to know how it could be done with metaprogram. I agree plain recursive version is much cleaner and easier to understand.
Regards